# Can we get answer 4 with double pointer by these statements in C?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

I got a question in [c](/questions/tagged/c) which is

```
int **ptr; 
printf("%d\n",**ptr);
```

how to print `4` with these statements in [c](/questions/tagged/c)?

Here I have two statements and answer should be `4`.

We can add any statements between two statements but without declaring new variable .

I tried lot more even with `malloc`, but I didn't get to solve this.

Comment: Could you please provide some code sample?

Comment: Ask your teacher and tell them to explain pointer-to-pointers... they should have done so before handing out this assignment.

Comment: @Lundin OP wrote: _We can add any statements between two statements but without declaring new variable_

Comment: @LPs Well that's a very stupid assignment then. I think some consensus over at meta at some point was that artificial nonsense questions with no real-world relevance were off-topic. Let me see if I can find it...

Comment: @Lundin [This may be what you're looking for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266979/contrived-homework-questions).

Answer (score 4):

What about?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int **ptr;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    **ptr = 4;
    printf("%d\n", **ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, as per *your* requirement, you can write

```
int **ptr; 
puts("4");
exit(0);
printf("%d\n",**ptr);
```

---

Actual *answer*:

Dont just try to write code without having a proper understanding of the requirement. First try to understand the purpose behind getting the lines of code typed.

In case, you're looking for the usage of pointer to pointer, you can try something like

```
int **ptr = NULL;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(**ptr));       //allocate memory to ptr first
if (ptr)                          //malloc is success?
{
   *ptr = malloc(sizeof*ptr);        //allocate memory to *ptr
}

if (*ptr) **ptr = 4;                 //finally, put the value in **ptr
printf("%d\n",**ptr);                //go ahead, print it

free(*ptr);             //don't forget this
free(ptr);              //don't forget that, either
```

but then, if you don't understand the ***why*** part, it'll be tough to get the ***how*** part.

*P.S- Code has inline comments to help you understand this one and give you a "pointer" for further reading.*

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int **ptr; 
    ptr = (int *[]){&(int){ 4 }};
    printf("%d\n",**ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Best one....if OP can understand. Maybe adding a link to compound literals can be more useful.

Comment: [compound literals](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/4135/compound-literals#t=201608260648364008599)